# Jenkins switch build folder

Tags: jenkins

I'm not even sure if I'm thinking about this correctly so I'm having difficulty googling it. I've got Jenkins set up and building a site and correctly sending the build artifacts over SSH to the live server.

My ideal workflow would be to ssh into the server, drop the new assets into a build folder, copy the old build files to a backup directory and drop all the new build files where the old build files used to be.

Not sure if that even makes sense or if there is a better way to do this. To be clear, I'm not talking about a single `.war` file or anything. I'm talking about a package of PHP files, images, CSS and other stuff.

I'm new to Jenkins in general so any help pointing me in the right direction is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Difficulty googling it? Try [Duckduckgo](https://duckduckgo.com/privacy). The search engine that doesn't track you. ;)

Comment: lol, the issue is more of, I'm not sure what I'm even looking for and all the results I'm finding don't seem to be what I need...I do like DDG though

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See the [ArtifactDeployer Plugin](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/ArtifactDeployer+Plugin):

> ArtifactDeployer plugin enables you to archive build artifacts to any remote locations such as to a separate file server.
>
> ...
>
> ArtifactDeployer is a complete alternative to the built-in Jenkins feature "Archiving artefacts' and it is aimed at providing an uniform deployment mechanism.

Add it to your project's config with ***Post-build Actions*** → <kbd>*Add post-build action*</kbd> → *[ArtifactDeployer] - Deploy the artifacts from build workspace to remote locations*.

or the [Flexible Publish Plugin](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Flexible+Publish+Plugin):

> ```
> ...
> [Send build artifacts over SSH]
> ...
> ```

Add it to your project's config with ***Post-build Actions*** → <kbd>*Add post-build action*</kbd> → *Flexible publish*.

or an idea I haven't tried myself yet, so no guarantees:

Configure your live server to be Jenkins slave node, create a project that is bound to this slave and use the [Copy Artifact Plugin](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Copy+Artifact+Plugin) therein:

> Adds a build step to copy artifacts from another project.

Add it to this project's config with ***Build*** → <kbd>*Add build step*</kbd> → *Copy artifacts from another project*.